# How can i make that everything after "," in .txt file will be checked separetly :)?

Tags: java, string

I need to improve this code that will read from a text file named `file.txt`

> sergy,many,mani,kserder

I would like to use this form :

```
file = login.getText();
if (file.equals("sergy"))
```

I just need to do something that will read everything in the text file separately and ignoring "," sign, or something else other than "," sign.

Comment: what have you tried so far? no one is going to write code for you

Comment: If you split the `file` string using the comma as delimiter, you will get an array of strings containing the different usernames. So: `String[] usernames = login.getText().split(",");`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could split the string by the `,` character and check if any of the array's elements are equal to the value you're looking for:

```java
file = login.getText();
if (Arrays.asList(file.split(",")).contains("sergy")) {
    // do something...
```